# Installing OCI8 with PHP 5.6 on centOs (vagrant)

Tags: php, linux, oracle, vagrant

From my understanding, and from previous installations, to install oci8 with php 5.6 on centOs I need to go through the fallowing steps:

- Install oracle-instantclient11.2-basic and oracle-instantclient11.2-devel with RPM.
- Install oci8 php extension with pecl.
- Add extension to php.ini.

That's what I did in my provision file.

```sh
installOracleInstantClient() {
  # ===================================================================
  # Install Oracle Support for PHP
  # ===================================================================
  if [ $(rpm -qa | grep -c 'oracle-instantclient') -eq 0 ]; then
    printLog 'Installing Oracle Client'
    yum --quiet -y install libaio

    yum -y --nogpgcheck --quiet install /opt/packages/oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm
    yum -y --nogpgcheck --quiet install /opt/packages/oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm

    cat > /etc/environment <<EOM
ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib"
EOM

    cat > /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh <<EOM
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
EOM

    export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
    export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
    export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin


    mkdir -p /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/network/admin -p
  fi
}

installPHP() {
  if [ $(rpm -qa | grep -c 'php') -eq 0 ]; then
    printLog 'Installing PHP'

    installGcc;

    installEPEL;

    installGit;

    printLog 'Adding php5.6 repositories'

    rpm -Uvh http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/extras/x86_64/Packages/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
    rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

    yum install yum-utils

    printLog 'installing php packages'
    yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install --quiet -y php php-common php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-devel php-ldap php-mbstring php-bcmath php-mysqlnd php-soap php-gd php-xml php-simplexml php-curl php-zip php-oci8 php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo

    # php-mssql php-sqlite php-mcrypt

    printLog 'Installing OCI8 extension for PHP'
    printf "instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64" | pecl install oci8-2.0.12

    # bits to add oci to php.ini
    echo 'extension=oci8.so' >> /etc/php.ini

    sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf"
    sudo ldconfig

  fi
}

installOracleInstantClient;
installPHP;
```

On machine provision I get the following errors:

```sh
default: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

default: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
 0
```

The same when I ssh into the machine and execute `php -v`.

Executing `ldd -r /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so` returns a bunch of `Undefined symbol` errors and the expected `libclntsh.so.18.1 => not found` line.

Also, `php -i` does not return the OCI8 block that's normally shown when oci8 is properly installed.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your script have both "yum instal ... php-oci8..." and "pecl install oci8", see my answer, but obviously second is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "remi-php56" repostiory, you don't need to build extension from sources, everything is in the repository ;)

- **php-oci8** which provides **oci8** version 2.0.12 and **pdo_oci8**

(the pecl command will only install the oci8 extension, not the PDO driver)

Packages are built using Oracle Client 18c and allow to connect to Server versions  18c, 12.2, 12.1 and 11.2.

Comment: I took out the pecl declaration and only have php-oci8 one, But now I get `default: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    default: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0` errors.

Comment: As I said, you need Oracle Client 18c, not 11.2

Comment: It was not an easy task, but I got it working. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Oracle client 18c.  I tried to install 11.2 oracle clients and make a symbolic link, but this does not work.

```
more /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf 
/u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0


# ldd /usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe2b368000)
libclntsh.so.18.1 => /u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/libclntsh.so.18.1 (0x00007f6bf18c3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6bf14f6000)
libmql1.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/libmql1.so (0x00007f6bf1296000)
libipc1.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/libipc1.so (0x00007f6bf0e24000)
libnnz18.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/libnnz18.so (0x00007f6bf06cf000)
libons.so => /u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/libons.so (0x00007f6bf047f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6bf027b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6beff79000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6befd5d000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f6befb43000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6bef93b000)
libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f6bef739000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f6bef520000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6bf5aab000)
libclntshcore.so.18.1 => /u01/app/oracle/product/18.5.0/libclntshcore.so.18.1 (0x00007f6beef3d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6beed27000)
```

Comment: 18c is not compatible with php 5.6 and for this particular old project I need 5.6

Comment: OCI8.so  module is compiled with libraries from Oracle 18c client. You need install old version OCI8 with oracle client 11.2.

Comment: symlink never works for library.... if soname are different... this means API is different....